# Preg_replace spaces between brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to get my head around regex, and I'm failing miserably.

I have a string, and I want to match and remove every space between two brackets.

For example:

```
This string (is an example).
```

Would become:

```
This string (isanexample).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback);

```
$str = "This string (is an example).";
$str = preg_replace_callback("~\(([^\)]*)\)~", function($s) {
    return str_replace(" ", "", "($s[1])");
}, $str);
echo $str; // This string (isanexample).
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm having a new problem now, but your demo works :) To elaborate, what if I wanted to run this over multiple lines, per line (look for brackets on each line, and removing the spaces between brackets on each line)?

Comment: It works already for multi-lines too. You can add to regexp `m` modifier but doesn't need. Test: `"This string (is an example).\n
            \t\t\t(foo bar baz) ..."`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this recursively. One regex won't do it.

```
$line = preg_replace_callback(
        '/\(.*\)/',
        create_function(
            "\$matches",
            "return preg_replace('/\s+/g','',\$matches);"
        ),
        $line
    );
```

What this does is the first pattern finds all of the text within the parens. It passes this match on to the named method (or in this case an anonymous method). The return of the method is used to replace what was matched.